# Rotate 2d image onclick android

Tags: android, imageview, scale, degrees

i want to rotate the image of imageView, i have scaled the image using matrix but having problem in rotation, i'm using the code...

```
int previousDegrees = 0;
        int degrees = 90;
        RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(previousDegrees,degrees,160,160);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        animation.setDuration(1000);//Set the duration of the animation to 1 sec.
        imageView.startAnimation(animation);
```

it rotates the image for a second and setback to original position.. is there any way that image could rotate onclick continuosly.. like on (0,90.180.270,360)degrees...
Any Help please!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set these parameters like so:

```
    animation.setFillEnabled(true);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

From [Android Developers Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html):

> If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished.

Comment: great...but it worked only for one direction, what to do if i want to rotate for some specified angles

Comment: With these params added to your code isn't that what it does - rotates 90 degrees (the value of your degrees variable) every time you click? To change direction you'd change the sign of the degrees variable. To change angle increment, change the value of the degrees variable.